# GIF quality generated in Android

Tags: android, image, android-ndk, gif, animated-gif

I am making an app that generates GIF from images taken on camera.

I have used two libraries to generate GIF, [this one](https://github.com/nbadal/android-gif-encoder/blob/master/GifEncoder.java) and [this one](https://github.com/wasabeef/gifflen-sample), but both generate GIF with awful quality. Image is posterized.

For example, here is the original image:

[image]

and here is the image generated by Gifflen library:

[image]

There are some apps on Google Store that generate GIF and don't destroy image quality. Is there a way to increase GIF quality (generation time increase is ok) or is there another library that can generate GIF?

**EDIT**

Like Wildopper said in the comment, it is probably *dithering* of the image that is causing the problem. Here is the explanation on *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither)*, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Gif is a 256 color max format. Don't expect fantastic quality with so few colors...
What seems to miss in your library is dithering. You may want to check the documentation to see if there's not an option to enable that.

Comment: Took me 1 minute of research to find that there's a dithering option in the quantise function of that library... I let you find out how it works ;)

Comment: Please tell me if it works. Thanks

Comment: I have "edited" original image in photoshop, and found that Giffle library posterizes the image to only around 20 layers.